# Are all HTTP Response codes valid for all HTTP verbs?

Tags: http, rest, soap, http-status-codes

Are there any invalid HTTP responses to for any specific HTTP verbs, or are all, theoretically, valid?

Comment: Why don't you read RFC 2616? I'm sure it says.

Comment: Eric Stein: RFC2616 is obsolete.

Comment: @EricStein Why do we have a QA site at all if all the information is available from source documentation?

Comment: @JulianReschke Yup, my bad. Replaced by RFCs 723X. In this case, the relevant RFC would be http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, all are valid. But of course they don't all make sense for all methods (such as a 201 upon GET).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all HTTP response codes are valid for HRRP verbs.

Basically, HTTP response codes are used to communicate with the outcome of HTTP requests, irrespective of the HTTP verbs used.